# what should I write on dockerfile for nginx and php:7.0-fpm?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, php-7

I want to work on nginx server and I use php:7.0-fpm
what should I write on dockerfile especially where begining from?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want your Nginx and Php container linked, you should use docker-compose, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_php
    image: php-fpm71:phalcon
    networks:
      - app
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./conf/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./shared:/shared
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_nginx
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./conf/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./shared:/shared
  mysql:
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - php
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./shared:/shared
networks:
  app:
```

Dockerfile_nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest

MAINTAINER Yakup Arslan <arslan.yakup@hotmail.com>

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
                    vim

RUN apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y && \
    apt-get clean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN rm -rf /var/log /var/cache
```

Dockerfile_php

```
#
# PHP-7.1 Phalcon Support
#
#

# Pull base image
FROM php:7.1-fpm

MAINTAINER Yakup Arslan <arslan.yakup@hotmail.com>

RUN curl -O https://codeload.github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tar.gz/v3.1.2
RUN tar xvzf v3.1.2
RUN cd cphalcon-3.1.2/build && ./install
RUN cd ../../ && rm -Rf cphalcon-3.1.2 && rm -Rf v3.1.2
RUN echo extension=phalcon.so > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phalcon.ini

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y \
                    git \
                    zip \
                    unzip \
                    libfreetype6-dev \
                    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
                    libmcrypt-dev \
                    libpng12-dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git /usr/local/lib/phalcon-devtools && \
    ln -svf /usr/local/lib/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/local/bin/phalcon && \
    chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/phalcon

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli \
                                      pdo_mysql \
                                      bcmath \
                                      gd

RUN apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y && \
    apt-get clean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /etc/php5 /etc/php/5* /usr/lib/php/20121212 /usr/lib/php/20131226

RUN rm -rf /var/log /var/cache
```

Comment: First of all thanks @yakupars . I must use compose.yml ? Can I do another way It's not just enough a dockerfile

Comment: You should create a docker account on [link](https://hub.docker.com) and commit your own image. After that, you can use your own image by calling `docker run -it yourusername/yourcustomimage bash` like so.